# Send/Receive image or XML file via KSOAP

Tags: ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

it may sounds stupid but i would like to know whether is it possible send and receive. maybe image/XML file vai kSOAP?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to transmit WebRowSet XML documents using kSOAP2.

http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/droid-chronicles-web-services-handling-complex-parameters

In this example I am sending an XML document from the web service to my Android based client. I hope this helps bro.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also please refrain from using signatures.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send image via ksoap by following steps:

- convert the `Image` into `byte[]`
- add `byte[]` of the image as property
- register SoapSerializationEnvelope with MarshalBase64() like this : `new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);`
- call your web service which takes `byte[]` as parameter

Then receiving the message you can convert the receieved `byte[]` into image file.