# How to Upload Image using web services

Tags: android

I have to upload an Image using KSOP web services.
I have to upload it on server Database.
Rest of my data in

```
String strquery = "insert into SNGTADMIN.sprint_mobile_task_dtl(SITE_NBR,SITE_ASSET_NAME,TASK_ID, PHYSICAL_CONDITION,VISIBLE_RUST,BLACK_SMOKE,ENCLOSURE_OIL_LEAK,BATTERY_FLUID_LEAK,AUTO_EXERCISE_STATUS,BATTERY_STATUS,TRANSFER_SWITCH_CONDITION,ALARM_NOT_RECV_BEFORE_REPAIR,ALARM_NOT_RECV_AFTER_REPAIR,ARRIVAL_FUEL_LEVEL,CUM_METER_READING,DESCRETE_ONSITE_WORK,FUTURE_RECOMMENDED_WORK,AFTERVISIT_EVAL_SUMMARY,ACCESS_INSTR_CLAR_NEEDED,MAINT_NOTES,FIELD_PROXIMITY) values('"+ siteId+ "','"+ asset_type+ "','1','"  + phyCondion+ "','"+ visbleRust + "','"             + heavyBlackSmoke+ "','"+ fuelOrOilLeak + "','" + bateryFluidLeaks+ "','"+ exceriseStatus
+ "','" + batteryStatus + "','" + transferSwitch+ "','" + beforeRepair  + "','" + ostRepair
+ "','" + fuelLevelUponArrival  + "','" + cumulativeRunHour+ "','"+ discretionaryWork               + "','" + additionalWork+ "','"+ evaluationSummaryAfterVisit+ "','"+ accessInstrustions
+ "','" + maintenanceNotes+ "','"+ fieldFarmProximity + "')";
```

and using

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("strSQl");
        pi.setValue(strquery);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
```

No idea how to add Image in this query. It work properly if i don't have send Image.

Help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491518/using-ksoap-for-file-transfer-from-android-application-to-web-service/15492158#15492158

Comment: one way is to encode image in base64 and decode it back on server

Comment: Hi Nirmal I have to add that image in a table column so....it should be in query.That's the problem.And I have no idea about database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that..!! I have done it by calling a `.asmx webservice`

The code for the web service can be coded as below:

```
 public class FileUploader : System.Web.Services.WebService

    {

[WebMethod]

public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)

{

    // the byte array argument contains the content of the file    
    // the string argument contains the name and extension    
    // of the file passed in the byte array    
    try    
    {    
        // instance a memory stream and pass the    
        // byte array to its constructor    
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);     

        // instance a filestream pointing to the    
        // storage folder, use the original file name    
        // to name the resulting file    
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath

                    ("~/TransientStorage/") +fileName, FileMode.Create); 


        // write the memory stream containing the original    
        // file as a byte array to the filestream    
        ms.WriteTo(fs); 


        // clean up    
        ms.Close();    
        fs.Close();    
        fs.Dispose();    

        // return OK if we made it this far    
        return "OK";    
    }

    catch (Exception ex)    
    {    
        // return the error message if the operation fails    
        return ex.Message.ToString();    
    }    
}
```

Hope this works for you.. if u need any other help. then do ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert images into `bytes` and then in `base64` string, and send this base64 string to server([1](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/how-send-captured-image-server-86481.S.103485592)) or create byte[] from image and add it as property to your request([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058413/1043882),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13844040/1043882))